# Proper way to request-file in Rebol 3 GUI (Saphir build)

Tags: filenames, rebol, rebol3

Is the following a correct way to get a file type value into a word using `request-file`?

```
view [
    text "Get file type value into a word"

    button "Target File Path" on-action [
        set 'fn1 request-file
    ]
 ]

 :fn1 ; a file value now in this word in our ad hoc scripting context
```

I just want to show how to have a pop-up file selection dialog, and then use that value in the REPL.

Comment: the issue is that using the set-word f1: in the block leaves us with no value in f1 back in the REPL where we are running our teaching script.

Answer (score 2):

It should suffice if you use

```
fn1: request-file
```

Comment: but back in the REPL, after the view has run and closed, f1 still has no value

Comment: That is not true here (check you are not making a typo in the variable name, the variable you examine must be the same as the one you set)